# Rails 5 Engine: Devise methods not defined in Controllers in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm using Devise(4.6.2) in a Rails Engine(5.2.3) and everything works fine in development. In my Rspec(3.8.2) controller tests, the Devise method `current_user` and before_action `authenticate_user!` both say undefined.

I've include in my rails_helper file:

```
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
```

but that has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller tests, call it like `subject.current_user`